# How to get filled rows length of 2D int array in c#

Tags: asp.net

I need to get the length of filled rows ( filled rows means a rows which contains at least one 1 ) of 2D int array in c#.
For ex..

```
1 1 1 0 1 
0 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0
```

Now the filled rows length=3 and col=4.
That is what i  need...

Comment: @ganesh as we can see you are new to SO.
you can expect the answers from peers when you post some of your efforts you made(Code).
if you don't post your efforts then peers including me simply assume that you have not tried anything at your end.

Answer (score 0):

I am expecting that you are storing these values in two dimensional integer array e.g.

```
int[][] a = {new int[] {1, 1, 0, 1}, new int[] {0, 1, 1, 1}, new int[] {1, 1, 1, 1}, new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0}};
```

Following is the LINQ for counting rows which has atleast one 1.

```
int filledRowsCount = a.Count(i => i.Any(ii => ii == 1));
```

Comment: I am using that array like,  Array intArray = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), maxRow, maxCol);
                        int[,] arrCheck1 = (int[,])intArray;

Answer (score 0):

```
    int[][] intarray = { new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, 
                         new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, 
                         new int[] { 1, 2, 3 },
                         new int[] { 1, 2, 3 } };
    **int c = intarray.Count();**//for rows Length = 4
      int b = intarray[0].Count();//for columns length =3
```

you can use also:

```
     int d = intarray.GetLength(0);//for rows length = 4
```

Comment: his question is specific to find rows which does contain atleast one 1